# Number of Dyck paths with k returns and b peaks

Tags: combinatorics

The number of Dyck paths from the origin to $(2n,0)$ which touch the $x$-axis $k+1$ times ($k$ internal touches) is given by
$$\frac{k}{2n-k}{2n-k \choose n}.$$

The number of Dyck paths from the origin to $(2n,0)$ which have $b$ peaks (i.e. local maxima) is given by the Narayana numbers
$$\frac{1}{n}{n \choose b}{n \choose b-1}.$$

My questions is: What is the number of Dyck paths from the origin to $(2n,0)$ which have both $k$ returns and $b$ peaks?

Thanks!

Comment: The description of the first count should say it touches the $x$ axis $k+1$ times. If $k=0$ the formula gives $0$ and there are no paths which touch the axis once. Maybe a better term is to say there are $k$ "returns", meaning that the first upward path from $(0,0)$ doesn't count as a return, but each later hit on the $x$ axis does. So with $1$ return in this sense, it counts the number of paths which start going up, do not touch the axis at internal points, and one final return to the axis at $(2n,0)$ (end of path).

Comment: The last sentence of the above comment was meant for the case of $k=1$ return. Of course the number of returns could be any $k$ between $1$ and $n,$ the $k=n$ case being a zig-zag path going up, down, up, down, ... in succession.

Comment: See Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [A253938](https://oeis.org/A253938): > A pyramid $F(n,p,r)$ of successive triangular arrays read by rows, relating Dyck path peaks and returns to the $x$ axis ($n = $ semilength of Dyck paths, $p =$ number of peaks, $r =$ returns to the $x$ axis).

Comment: Do you have a reference to the first formula?

Answer (score 3):

This has been computed by Emeric Deutsch. See section 6.5 of the reference below. The formula is given as equation (6.20).

$$\mbox{# Dyck $n$-paths with $k$ returns and $b$ peaks}=\left\{\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l}
\frac{k}{b}{n-1\choose b-1}{n-1-k\choose b-k}&\mbox{if $b>0$, $k<n$},\\
1&\mbox{if $b=k=n$},\\
0&\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$

I think this is equivalent to Roger Ford’s formula, but I thought it would be a useful addition as it includes a proof.

---

Emeric Deutsch, *Dyck path enumeration*, In Discrete Mathematics, Volume 204, Issues 1–3, 1999, Pages 167-202 ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98003719))

Answer (score 0):

If $n$=semi length of Dyck Path, $p$=peaks and $r$=returns then:

$$F(n,p,r)=\frac{r(n-1)!(n-r-1)!}{p!(p-r)!(n-p)!(n-p-1)!}$$

If $n=p=r$ then $F(n,p,r)=1$.

Example:
$$F(7,4,3)=\frac{3(7-1)!(7-3-1)!}{4!(4-3)!(7-4)!(7-4-1)!}=45$$
There are 45 Dyck Paths with a semi length of 7, 4 peaks and 3 returns.